# Unchecked generics or object boxing?

Tags: java, generics

I have method that returns component (Object that extends *Component* interface) instance by the type (class).

What is the best or the right way to return component? Using uncheked generics or returning component as *Component* type. Or is there a better way then these two I found out? Actually I would like to get component by the return type specified in statement (ex. `ConcreteComponent cc = this.getComponent();`);

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getComponent(final Class<? extends T> type) {
    for (Component c : this.components) {
        if (c.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type)) { return (T) c; }
    }
    return null;
}

public Component getComponent2(final Class<? extends Component> type) {
    for (Component c : this.components) {
        if (c.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type)) { return c; }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have the logic of `Class.isAssignableFrom()` backwards.

If the objective is to retrieve the first component that is assignment-compatible with a given type, then I would probably write it like so:

```
public <T extends Component> T getComponent(Class<T> type) {
    for (Component c : this.components) {
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass())) {
            return type.cast(c);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Notes:

1. It is counterproductive to use a wildcard in the type parameter for argument `type`.  Using a generic method already gives you all the flexibility you need, and may help you avoid needing to use an explicit type parameter when you call the function.
2. `Class.cast()` is a typesafe (sort of) alternative to literal casting.  You should be able to do without suppressing type safety warnings if you use it.
3. You cannot get the actual class of the selected component as the formal return type of the method, because that class cannot be known at compile time.  (I'm not certain whether you were actually asking for this, but it sounded like maybe you were.)

Comment: `type.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass())` can also be `type.isInstance(c)`.

Comment: @Radiodef - good point, and `isInstance()` is probably a better choice for this, but it doesn't let me correct Mato's usage of `isAssignableFrom()`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't believe `ConcreteComponent cc = this.getComponent();` is possible in java at this time.  It would require figuring out the class of the object backwards, and that doesn't seem possible.

That said, I would recommend this: It uses [`Class.cast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) which avoids the warning, and also cleans up the generics bit (skipping the unneeded wildcard and specifying that it extends component).

```
public <T extends Component> T getComponent(final Class<T> type) {
    for (Component c : this.components) {
        if (c.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return type.cast(c);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```